# pandoc pdf customize toc

Tags: pdf, latex, pandoc, tableofcontents

My pandoc pdf output of toc is not so perfect.
As you can see there is pagebreak after chapter 4.

I like to have always at least one subsection for each chapter shown on same page. So in this case it would be better if chapter 4 would start on new page.

[image: TOC chapter title]

Code for minimal example and intermediate files can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/robie2011/89d3e58994ffc4d194fb25d378973619

commandline:

```
pandoc -o test.pdf --toc example.md
```

Pandoc version:
pandoc 2.7.3
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.5.4, texmath 0.11.2.2, skylighting 0.8.1

Comment: Can you make a minimal working example and share the intermediate tex file?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce the problem with your example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPi71.png

Comment: This is basically a LaTeX issue... if you figure out the correct LaTeX, you can put it in the `header-includes` field in the [yaml metadata](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block).

Comment: @samcarter that’s strange. Try to delete 14 or 15 lines from chapter A.

Comment: @robie2011 It would be much easier if you would share the intermediate tex file ....

Comment: @robie2011 Thanks for updating your question! The problem is caused by the `parskip` package. Can you try to compile without it as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480592 ?